# Wordpress add new page blank page

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem with wordpress - there is a blank page when trying to add a new page or trying updating existing page.

Info:

- fresh wordpress install
- reinstaled few times already so no corrupt files
- plugins and theme checked
- memory limit added
- other sites on the same server working

Comment: check header of response coming from server to request. may be 503 or 500 ...

Comment: Use wp_debug to get the error

Comment: Check with `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` in your `wp-config.php` file.